# Placing cursor in contenteditable="true" element which has SVG element top of it (rect) for highlighting text content

Tags: javascript, html, svg

In our web application we are having content-editable area to input the text. Along with this, we use SVG element to highlight the particular word when user click some button in toolbar (adding details like annotation, spellcheck and custom design), these SVG's are not placed between the content since we don't want to split content, those are placed at bottom of the document body, and we move those using top and left attributes in SVG element with position: absolute and z-index: 1000.

Note that we set "pointer-events: none" to those SVG elements since we want users to click and modify the text, otherwise we won't be able to place the cursor in the highlighted text content.

It works well, but now we have a requirement if user mouseover the highlighted text then we need to display dialog to expand the details of highlighted text, in this case we are enabling "pointer-events: auto" to SVG elements to achieve mouseover event but we are unable to place the cursor in highlighted text content.

Is there any way to add mouse events to SVG elements when we apply pointer-events: none
or
Is there any way to place the cursor in highlighted text content when pointer-events: auto

As I mentioned I don't want to split the content by span or any other element to achieve this?

I tried to explain my situation below, any suggestions or ideas are much appreciated.

Thanks,
Kumar

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>SVG testing</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color: lightgrey;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 1.5;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        .editdiv-wrap{
            width: 50%;
            margin: 100px auto;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .editdiv{
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .markers svg{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1000;
        }
        .marker-comment{
            fill: #47ae54;
            stroke: #3a8343;
            opacity: 0.25;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body spellcheck="false">
    <div class="editdiv-wrap" contenteditable="true">
        <div class="editdiv" contenteditable="true">This document content line having SVG with <b>pointer-events: "none"</b>. I can able to place the cursor in highlighted content but mouseover is not working in svg element.</div>
        <div class="editdiv" contenteditable="true">This document content line having SVG with <b>pointer-events: "auto"</b>. I can able to add listener for mouseover but I am unable to place the cursor in highlighted text content.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="markers">
        <svg id="svg1" class="marker-comment" width="71px" height="19px" pointer-events="none" style="left: 518px; top: 103px;"><rect width="71px" height="19px" x="0px" y="0px"></rect></svg>
        <svg id="svg2" class="marker-comment" width="71px" height="19px" pointer-events="auto" style="left: 518px; top: 170px;"><rect width="71px" height="19px" x="0px" y="0px"></rect></svg>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // not working
        var svg1 = document.getElementById("svg1");
        svg1.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
            console.log("able to mouseover svg1");
        })
        // working
        var svg = document.getElementById("svg2");
        svg.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
            console.log("able to mouseover svg2");
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```